# IntelliJ doesn't detect that a Java project is using Maven for building, even if it offers some maven functions (but not the clean install ones)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've installed *intelliJ* and it targets an existing `Java` project.

It marks `pom.xml` file with a special icon, but no *Maven* windows is available and if it offers me to *Reload Maven Project* or to *Download sources and documentation* there's no way to perform a clean install or something like that.

As if my project wasn't recognized as a *Maven* Project.

How can I tell to *IntelliJ* that this project uses *Maven* for building ?

[image: Maven tool is lacking]
(Maven tool is missing. The `comptes-france` project is red because one of its dependencies doesn't compile because maven has not been invoked to get one `org.unit` tool)

P.S. : of course, if I go on `comptes-france` directory and run a `mvn clean install` from a command line, it works : the project itself compiles well, alone. It's *IntelliJ* that doesn't detect it well.

[image]

---

@Andrey it seems that Reload Maven project leads to an *IntelliJ* bug :

```
2021-09-20 08:07:17,774 [ 784855]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Failed to update Maven indices for: [local] /home/lebihan/.m2/repository 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.convertSettings(MavenServerManager.java:510)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.lambda$updateIndex$2(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.performCancelable(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.updateIndex(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateContext(MavenIndex.java:401)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateOrRepair(MavenIndex.java:347)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.updateOrRepair(MavenIndices.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.doUpdateIndices(MavenIndicesManager.java:371)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$3.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:335)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:510)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

---

Glad to you help, all, I succeeded in having the *Maven* Tools, and this is convenient.
But using "*Build Project (Ctrl-F9)*" still doesn't make it build correctly, while doing an Lifecycle -> install from *Maven* tools on the root project does.

My project isn't fully understood as a *Maven* project yet.

Comment: Close the project and delete the intellij files. Then, open the project but select the POM as the project, not the folder. Intellij will then detect the maven project.

Comment: You can open Maven tool window via View | Tool Windows | Maven.

Comment: `The comptes-france project is red because one of its dependencies doesn't compile because maven has not been invoked to get one org.unit tool)` Do you see this module's Maven pom.xml file imported as Maven project? Does **Reload** action complete successfully?

Comment: @Andrey I've edited my post to reply to you and add informations.

Comment: What current problem do you have?

Comment: @Andrey "Build" menu doesn't seems to follow the dependencies of the underlying maven files, and declare missing some packages that are here.

Comment: This exception has been fixed in 2021.3 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271045 The EAP build is available from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ But it could also help to re-import project afresh: delete existing `.idea` project configuration directory and open the main pom.xml file of the project using File | Open action.

Comment: You are not using the Maven standard directory structure.  I do not see src/main/java or src/test/java folders.  Are they underneath the modules?

Answer (score 2):

> Close the project and delete the intellij files. Then, open the project but select the POM as the project, not the folder. Intellij will then detect the maven project.

Comment [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249958/intellij-doesnt-detect-that-a-java-project-is-using-maven-for-building-even-if/76955055#comment122397347_69249958) by [Software Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051454/software-engineer).

Answer (score 1):

I used the File/Invalidate caches and there I clicked (using the default settings) on the Invalidate and Restart button. The whole project was reloaded and during this process I had a pop windows in the bottom-right corner which was said to allow maven project loading. I clicked on it and the magic happened, IntelliJ started to recognise my project as a maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 --> Delete all ".idj" from each folder that does not read including the parent pom folder

Step 2 --> Click on the maven refresh button to search again. I hope I have helped, this is how I have achieved it, when there are multiple projects it gives many problems intellij.

[image]